# should VSE 2013 for Windows with Update be installed on VSE 2013 for Windows Desktop

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Should this:

[Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 2 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=42305), which contains an update that has bug fixes, be installed on top of Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop? Where is the information on the web that makes the answer obvious (except stackoverflow after I select the acceptable answer) ?

**Edit** To clarify: are updates to the VSE Windows product intended to be applied to a VSE Windows Desktop product (that lacks the Phone stuff, etc)?

Comment: Nothing is very obvious about whether or not you want to be a beta tester.  VS betas have rather a poor track record, it often is pretty doggone hard to get rid of it again.  If you depend on VS to get your job done then only ever consider installing it in a VM.  "Where do I find the answer" questions are not on topic here.

Comment: This question should have been phrased: Are updates to the Windows product intended to be applied to a Windows Desktop product (that lacks the Phone stuff, etc).

Comment: "for Windows" was made for Store apps.  "for Desktop" was made for desktop apps.  Afaik the only reason that Express update is made available because you need it for Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing it will put VSE 2013 for Windows in the list of installed programs, next to VSE 2013 for Windows Desktop, so it can be inferred that the first was not meant to provide bug fixes to the second.